# ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema/ Express js with DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-dynamodb

I have been stuck for quite a while trying to fix the ValidationException error. I am using Javascript v3 and DynamoDBClient.

Things I have done:

- Made sure the aws credentials can be used with my standalone react application (still in the process of self-learning AWS)
- Did a simple ScanCommand to bring over data from DynamoDB to frontend (works)
- Verified that data is passed to the backend from frontend sucessfully (works)

This is my DynamoDB table design:

The table name is Users,
[image]

My credential and access key: (root user not created user)

[image]

For backend, I am using Express js:

```
import Express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import path from "path";
import bodyparser from "body-parser";
import {DynamoDBClient} from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";
import {GetCommand} from "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb";
import {fromEnv} from "@aws-sdk/credential-providers"; // This is required
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

const aws_creds = path.join(process.cwd(), "../", "env/", "awsbackend.env")
console.log("ENV File: " + aws_creds.toString());

// Load environment variable into process environment
dotenv.config({path: aws_creds});

// NOTE: This will only work after loading to process environment
console.log(process.env.backendport);
console.log(process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID);

var capstone_proj = Express();

capstone_proj.use(cors());

capstone_proj.use(bodyparser.json());

var creds = fromEnv(); // No matter what, this is required

let DBnoSQL = new DynamoDBClient({
  region: process.env.region,
  credentials: creds,
});

capstone_proj.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  const { Usrname, Password } = req.body;

  console.log(req.body);

  try {
    const command = new GetCommand({
      TableName: "Users",
      Key : {
         "Username": {S: Usrname}
      }
    });
    const data = await DBnoSQL.send(command);

    if (!data.Item) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Wrong login credentials' });
    }

    const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(
      Password,
      data.Item.Password_Hash.S,
    );

    if (isPasswordValid) {
      return res.status(200).json({ message: "Login successful" });
    } else {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: "Wrong login credentials" });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
    return res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
  }
});


capstone_proj.listen(process.env.backendport, () => {
    console.log("Backend listening on " + process.env.backendport)
})

//getdata();
```

The error that I am getting:

```
Error: ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema
    at throwDefaultError (D:\Coding Workspaces\Capstone\backend-AWS\node_modules\@smithy\smithy-client\dist-cjs\default-error-handler.js:8:22)
    at D:\Coding Workspaces\Capstone\backend-AWS\node_modules\@smithy\smithy-client\dist-cjs\default-error-handler.js:18:39
    at de_GetItemCommandError (D:\Coding Workspaces\Capstone\backend-AWS\node_modules\@aws-sdk\client-dynamodb\dist-cjs\protocols\Aws_json1_0.js:1554:20)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async D:\Coding Workspaces\Capstone\backend-AWS\node_modules\@smithy\middleware-serde\dist-cjs\deserializerMiddleware.js:7:24
    at async D:\Coding Workspaces\Capstone\backend-AWS\node_modules\@aws-sdk\lib-dynamodb\dist-cjs\baseCommand\DynamoDBDocumentClientCommand.js:26:34
    at async D:\Coding Workspaces\Capstone\backend-AWS\node_modules\@aws-sdk\middleware-signing\dist-cjs\awsAuthMiddleware.js:14:20
    at async D:\Coding Workspaces\Capstone\backend-AWS\node_modules\@smithy\middleware-retry\dist-cjs\retryMiddleware.js:27:46
    at async D:\Coding Workspaces\Capstone\backend-AWS\node_modules\@aws-sdk\middleware-logger\dist-cjs\loggerMiddleware.js:7:26
    at async file:///D:/Coding%20Workspaces/Capstone/backend-AWS/index.js:46:18 {
  '$fault': 'client',
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 400,
    requestId: 'N9OAQBOPOSM5NV38FE5FNCLMQ3VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG',
    extendedRequestId: undefined,
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  },
  __type: 'com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing to not here is this:

`at async D:\Coding Workspaces\Capstone\backend-AWS\node_modules\@aws-sdk\lib-dynamodb\dist-cjs\baseCommand\DynamoDBDocumentClientCommand.js:26:34`

Your app is trying to use DynamoDBDocumentClientCommand but you are not using the document client, you use the low-level client.

```
import {DynamoDBClient, GetItemCommand} from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";
//import {GetCommand} from "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb";

  const command = new GetItemCommand({
      TableName: "Users",
      Key : {
         "Username": {S: Usrname}
      }
    });
```

Also, if no data is returned it does not mean bad credentials, but rather the item did not exist. You should use the exceptions which DynamoDB returns to you to provide more granular information rather than assuming credentials are wrong.

```
 if (!data.Item) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Item does not exist' });
    }
```